# dynamic type casting

Tags: c#

Now I think it is clear.
I have created a object oriented database in C#.NET where two classes are there. Student and contacts. Contacts are inside student. I am Retrieving all objects in Object array. Class student has fields `name` and `age`, while contact has `mobileID`.

Now I am creating a query through textboxes. Created textboxes. one for select and one for from. in from(var1) class name is accepted , while in select(var2), field name is accepted. If user want to see name of all the objects, then var2 "name" should be input; but I am not able to get this message

```
messageBox.show(obj[0] as Student).var2);
```

it is giving error var2 ,     'object' does not contain a definition for 'var2' and no extension method 'var2' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Same issue if instead of Student if I give var1 `messageBox.show(obj[0] as var1).var2);`

Can I do this?

Comment: Opening and closing parentheses count doesn't match

Comment: Count your parenthesis, you have to have same number of ( and ) on one line/statement.

Comment: If you know the instance is `Student`, why don't you actually cast to `Student` once and work from there... having a whole load of casts all over the place each time you access a property isn't exactly performant...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using reflection.

`var2` is a variable containing the name of a property.  You can't just say `obj.var2` and get the value of the property whose name is in var2.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
var objType = obj[0].GetType();
var propInfo = objType.GetProperty(var2);
var value = propInfo.GetValue(obj[0], null);
```

Comment: It is giving error "object refernce not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: It is giving error "object refernce not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Bharto Joshi - Check which object reference is null.  If it's `propInfo` then `obj[0]` doesn't have a public property named whatever is stored in `var2`.  Check the value of `var2`, and also look at the overload of `GetProperty` that includes binding flags if the property you're after is inherited or is not public.  If `obj[0]` itself is null then I can't help you.  You can't get the value of a property from a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks strange, the number of closing parenthesis doesn't match the opening. Maybe:

```
MessageBox.show((obj[0] as Student).var2);
```

Also make sure that this `va2` property is public inside the `Student` class:

```
public string var2 { get; set; }
```